# How to avoid git interactive rebase messing up a pull request?

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control, pull-request

I contribute to an open source project on GitHub. Created a pull request, which was reviewed by the maintainer, who asked me to rework some stuff. In the meantime other good people contributed too. So first I used `git rebase master` to rebase my pull request on top of the latest `master` branch, and then `git rebase -i HEAD~5`, the interactive rebase feature to fix some of my commits, then `git push --force` to my own remote branch.

However, after that, GitHub thinks that my branch can no longer be merged into the `master` branch, due to conflicts. In fact, it thinks that some other commits (not mine) were added to my branch, which obviously conflict with the same ones in `master`.

What did I do wrong, and how can I do it correcty?

### More details

Assume the `master` branch has the following history

```
(master) A -> B -> C -> D
```

Then I commit `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, so my branch history is:

```
(my-branch) A -> B -> C -> D -> X -> Y -> Z
```

Let's also assume that someone committed and pushed `E` to `master` in the meantime:

```
(master) A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

So first I do `git rebase master` on `my-branch`. After this my branch history is:

```
(my-branch) A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> X -> Y -> Z
```

Then I do `git rebase -i HEAD~5` like this:

```
pick D
pick E
pick X
sqash Y
edit Z
```

Note that I don't change `D` or `E`.
After this my history looks like:

```
(my-branch) A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> X -> Z
```

Then I do `git push myremote my-branch --force`.

After this, GitHub claims that my pull request can no longer be merged, because commits `C`, `D`, and `E` on my branch conflict with `C`, `D`, and `E` on `master`. Note that I didn't edit these commits, only my own (and `C` was not even part of the interactive rebase).

Why is `git` behaving like this?
How can I avoid git interactive rebase messing up a pull request?

Answer (score 5):

You must be a little bit careful with interactive rebase (or any rebase, really, but it tends to show up much more often with interactive rebase since it's so flexible).

It may help to think about the commit graph in more detail.  Specifically, this kind of drawing is inherently somewhat wrong:

> ```
> (master) A -> B -> C -> D
> ```

It's much better to draw this as:

```
A  <-B  <-C  <-D   <--master
```

The key item here is putting the branch name on the right, with an arrow coming out of it.  The rest of the arrows can be converted into straight linkages:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

because all commits are read-only.  It's hard to draw the internal arrows, so knowing that they literally *can't* change, we can draw them as connecting lines.  The reason to draw them in, at least initially, is that the arrows are connected to the *children*, not the parents: the children know who their parent commits are—`D` knows to reach back to `C`, for instance—but the parents have no idea who their children are.  There is no way to go from `A` to `B`; we can only go from `B` back to `A`, and then realize that hey, we got here from `B`, so there must be a path from `A` to `B` after all.

This is a key realization when working with Git: ***it does everything backwards.***

The reason all of this matters has to do with what happens during parallel development.  As you said, you made `X`, `Y`, and `Z`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           X--Y--Z   <-- my-branch
```

Your `X` knows about `D`, but `D`—which you share with several other Git repositories—knows nothing about your `X`.

Meanwhile, someone else made `E`, which also points back to `D`.  If we imagine some sort of godlike super-repository that somehow knows about `E` *and* `X-Y-Z` all at the same time, we can draw it like this:

```
           E   <-- third-person
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master
          \
           X--Y--Z   <-- my-branch
```

and then they—"they" here being the open-source group on GitHub—adopted this third person's `E` into their own `master`:

```
           E   <-- master, third-person
          /
A--B--C--D
```

(they still don't know about your `X-Y-Z` yet, perhaps, so we just take them off the drawing).  Now you run `git fetch upstream` to your local computer to pick up the GitHub repository versions, and in *your* repository, which *does* still have `X-Y-Z`, you have:

```
           E   <-- upstream/master
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master, origin/master
          \
           X--Y--Z   <-- my-branch (HEAD), origin/my-branch
```

(I'm assuming here that your `origin` represents *your* GitHub fork, and your `upstream` represents the original GitHub repository from which you made your fork).

#### Without interactive rebase

When you run `git rebase upstream/master`, or make your `master` point to commit `E` and run `git rebase master`, you have your Git make *copies* of commits `X`, `Y`, and `Z`:

```
             X'-Y'-Z'  <-- my-branch (HEAD)
            /
           E   <-- upstream/master
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master, origin/master
          \
           X--Y--Z   <-- origin/my-branch
```

(this drawing assumes you have not bothered to update your `master`; if you have, we could draw it a bit differently).

These copies—the ones labeled with tick marks, `X'-Y'-Z'`—are ready for you to force-push to your fork.  Assuming you do that at this point, your fork will have them and the original `X-Y-Z` chain will be abandoned:

```
             X'-Y'-Z'  <-- my-branch (HEAD), origin/my-branch
            /
           E   <-- upstream/master
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master, origin/master
          \
           X--Y--Z   [abandoned]
```

If we update your own `master` and `origin/master` as well, we'll be able to redraw all of this as the simpler:

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
             \
              X'-Y'-Z'   <-- my-branch (HEAD), origin/my-branch
```

(all of these being in *your* repository on *your* computer—on GitHub, in your fork, these are just named `master` and `my-branch` without the `origin/` part and there are no `upstream/` parts at all).

Your pull request will automatically be updated to use the new `X'-Y'-Z'` commits, which simply add on to commit `E`—so if *their* repository still ends at commit `E`, there should be no issues with them absorbing your commits.

#### With interactive rebase

If you wish to squash `Y'` into `X'` and do something with `Z'`'s message, you can do that now using interactive rebase.  Or, you can do all of this *instead of* the initial rebase:

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git rebase -i upstream/master
```

Note that `upstream/master` here really means "commit `E`" in our graph, which is one of those that has `E` as `upstream/master` and either `Z` or `Z'` as your own tip of `my-branch`.

Git will now make a list of the three commits that are on `my-branch` but are not on `upstream/master`, i.e., starting from `Z` or `Z'` and working backwards towards `A`, list those commits, then *remove* from that list, all commits starting from `E` and working backwards.  These three commits' hash IDs will go into the three `pick` commands.

You can now change one to squash and one to edit as before: since you're working *only* on your commits, and not on anyone else's, you won't be copying anyone else's commits to new and different commits.  When you're done editing, you will have new commits yet again—if you already copied `X` to `X'`, `Y` to `Y'`, and `Z` to `Z'`, now you have `X"` which is `X'` + `Y'` (squashed), and `Z"` which is the edited version of `Z'` but connects to `X"`:

```
              X"-Z"   <-- my-branch (HEAD)
             /
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master, origin/master, upstream/master
             \
              X'-Y'-Z'   <-- origin/my-branch
```

You can now force-push these to your fork, so that their `my-branch` (which you are calling `origin/my-branch` in your Git repository here) changes to point to commit `Z"`, and now your fork is updated again and your pull request is auto-updated and you're (still, or finally for real) ready for them to look at `X"` and `Z"`.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome and detailed explanation. However it's still unclear to me why my original approach failed. Since I ran the interactive rebase *after* I already rebased on top of the upstream master, I don't see what went wrong.

Comment: @Venemo: interactive rebase will normally try to "fast forward" existing commits rather than copying them, but given your outcome, it must have copied the commit we've been labeling `E` to a new `E'`. Your pull request then has your `E'` atop `D`, which conflicts with their `E` atop `D` (or the same thing with *two* copies, atop `C`). It's hard to tell without seeing the actual *commit graph* and GitHub insists on hiding the actual graph (their "network graph" is something else entirely, and never seems to be quite right anyway).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting it. Why does interactive rebase "copy" `E` or anything else?

Comment: I understand why it copies the commits that I actually modify, but not why it would copy any other.

Comment: As I said, normally it *won't*, but there are conditions under which it's forced to: if you are making any change (on purpose or by accident), including changing their parent linkage, for instance; or if you use `--no-ff`.

Comment: But I didn't change their parant linkage (as far as I know; or did I?), nor did I use `--no-ff`.

Comment: I don't see how you would have based on your question; but `git rebase -i` has a lot of flexibility and it's possible you did something that you didn't show here, or don't remember. An exact log of everything you did, or a method of repeating the problem, would be required.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to specify a merging strategy on the command line to always resolve conflicts by taking changes from the upstream repository.

```
git rebase -s recursive -X ours master
```

Although it's not intuitive, "ours" and "theirs" become reversed during a rebase.  So this would resolve any conflicts using the merged, upstream changes. To always take your changes, during a rebase, pass "theirs"  (More details: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---strategy-optionltstrategy-optiongt)

Do your interactive rebase to clean up any history, force push to your fork.. and there should not be any conflicts from GitHub's perspective during the PR.